# Update/Add choices of a Choice field of SharePoint list using REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I want to update the options of the Choice field of the SharePoint List. Is there any way to update the choices using the REST API?

Below is the code i am using:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "https://ts.accenture.com/sites/LearningProducts/DTP/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('DTP')/fields?$filter=(TypeAsString eq 'Choice') and (Title eq  'Status')",
        type: "POST",
        data:{
  "__metadata": {
    "type": "SP.FieldChoice"
  },
    "Choices": { 'results': ['Detractor'] }
},

        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
             "X-RequestDigest": $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val(),
             "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
              "IF-MATCH": "*",


        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }

    });
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Did you try using 'PATCH' operation instead of 'POST' ?

Comment: @UBK i am getting error A token was not recognized in the JSON content. i tried with Patch also but same error.

Comment: Please use JSON.stringify(..) to convert the 'data' object or value to a JSON string. Like this: var messageData = {
  "__metadata": {
    "type": "SP.FieldChoice"
  },
    "Choices": { 'results': ['Detractor'] }
};

data: JSON.stringify(messageData)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample tested script for your reference.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateChoiceField() {
        $.ajax({
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('mylist')/Fields(guid'2e257823-b8c6-411d-80f3-9f2cc913be0f')",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({ "__metadata": { "type": "SP.FieldChoice" }, "Choices": { "__metadata": { "type": "Collection(Edm.String)" }, "results": ["ChoiceA", "ChoiceB", "ChoiceC"] } }),

            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val(),
                "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-HTTP-Method": "PATCH",
                "IF-MATCH": "*",
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(error));
            }
        });
    }
</script>
<input id="Button1" onclick="updateChoiceField()" type="button" value="updateChoiceField" />
```

Update:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function GetFieldOptions() {
            return $.ajax({
                url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('mylist')/Fields(guid'2e257823-b8c6-411d-80f3-9f2cc913be0f')",
                type: "GET",                
                headers: {
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",                    
                    "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
                }
            })
        }
        function updateChoiceField() {
            GetFieldOptions().done(function (data) {
                var FieldOptions = data.d.Choices.results;
                FieldOptions.push("NewOption");
                $.ajax({
                    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('mylist')/Fields(guid'2e257823-b8c6-411d-80f3-9f2cc913be0f')",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ "__metadata": { "type": "SP.FieldChoice" }, "Choices": { "__metadata": { "type": "Collection(Edm.String)" }, "results": FieldOptions } }),

                    headers: {
                        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                        "X-RequestDigest": $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val(),
                        "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                        "X-HTTP-Method": "PATCH",
                        "IF-MATCH": "*",
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
                    }
                });
            })

        }
    </script>
    <input id="Button1" onclick="updateChoiceField()" type="button" value="updateChoiceField" />
```

Comment: thanks it worked...but it is replacing all the field choices with the new ones specified in array. How i can append the choices with the existing ones without overwriting them?

Comment: Add the logic .