# Add a new choice option to a choice field with write-in using REST without erasing existing options

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, choice-field, power-automate

When a folder is created in a library I would like the Name of the folder to populate a choice field.  I would like to use REST in Power Automate to add a choice to a choice column with write-in enabled but it overwrites the other choices.  Can I get the current choices as an array then add them to the item I am wanting to update?  I am not sure how to go about this. The following is an example of my code:
`{ 
   "__metadata":
    {
          "type": "SP.FieldChoice" },
          "Choices": { "__metadata":
             { "type": "Collection(Edm.String)" }, 
           "results": NewChoiceOption  #How can I add the current choices here so that I don't overwrite?

}
}

`

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/279791/8992

Answer (score 1):

You could take the following steps:

1. Initialize 2 variables, one type is array and one type is string.
2. Use rest api to get the choice field.
3. Parse the JSON "Body", you would get the current choices as array "results"
4. Set the array variable to "results", then append one value to the array varibale.
5. Set the string varibale to the arrary variable.
6. Update the choice field.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]